# Integration between ASP.NET & Google Apps

Tags: asp.net

I am doing a research on integrating a CMS (DotNetNuke, Sitefinity, ... etc ...) or even any other ASP.NET application with Google Apps or Engine.

For instance, I would like the user to login on my Website, automatically to get logged in with Google. Another example, to allow the user to collaborate on a Document from inside the ASP.NET Website, maybe a link to it or so would suffice.

The major point is having the ASP.NET the core or base that utilizes Google apps from inside!

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Thank you & regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find a lot of information regarding this issue exploring [Google API for developers](http://code.google.com/intl/en/more/) and [some wrappers to it on Codeplex](http://www.codeplex.com/site/search?query=Google&stableOnly=true&sortBy=Relevance&licenses=|). There is also exist [.NET Client Library](http://code.google.com/intl/ru/apis/gdata/client-cs.html) provided by Google.

For instance, to request a Calendar feed using the C# client library, for a user with email address "jo@gmail.com" and password "mypassword", use the following code:

```
// Create a query and service object:

FeedQuery query = new FeedQuery();
Service service = new Service("cl", "exampleCo-exampleApp-1"));
// Set your credentials:
service.setUserCredentials("jo@gmail.com", "mypassword");

// Create the query object:
query.Uri = new Uri("http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/jo@gmail.com/private/full");

// Tell the service to query:
AtomFeed calFeed = service.Query(query);
```

Comment: Hi apros, Thanks a lot for the information. I will need to do a lot of research on what you mentioned!

How reasonable it is to have such a model? .NET app, integrating it with Google Apps?

Thanks